# How to show/hide a border using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 10 square boxes with different colors. I'm trying to show a border for the square that the user clicks on, and hide the border of the previous square. So far I have this, but I somehow get `Cannot read property 'style' of null`. My idea is to hide the current box border, then show a border for the new box that the user clicks.

Here is the jsFiddle of what I want. However, it doesn't seem to work. I can only use Javascript and can't use JQuery
https://jsfiddle.net/5op0d7zs/7/

```js
var currentBoxNum = 1;

function changeColor(background, boxNum) {
  document.getElementById("box" + currentBoxNum).style.borderStyle = "none";
  currentBoxNum = boxNum;
  document.getElementById("box" + currentBoxNum).style.borderStyle = "solid";
}
box1.onclick = function() { changeColor("#e6e2cf",1); }
box2.onclick = function() { changeColor("#dbcaac",2); }
box3.onclick = function() { changeColor("#c9cbb3",3); }
box4.onclick = function() { changeColor("#bbc9ca",4); }
box5.onclick = function() { changeColor("#a6a5b5",5); }
box6.onclick = function() { changeColor("#b5a6ab",6); }
box7.onclick = function() { changeColor("#eccfcf",7); }
box8.onclick = function() { changeColor("#eceeeb",8); }
box9.onclick = function() { changeColor("#bab9b5",9); }
```

```html
<div class="colors">
  <div id="box1">1</div>
  <div id="box2">2</div>
  <div id="box3">3</div>
  <div id="box4">4</div>
  <div id="box5">5</div>
  <div id="box6">6</div>
  <div id="box7">7</div>
  <div id="box8">8</div>
  <div id="box9">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added how I call the function.

Comment: Your code seems to work as it is? Notice, that relying on global variables represnting ids is very error prone, don't use it.

Comment: @AndyNguyen Can you please reproduce this on sandbox, jsfiddle, or stackblitz?
So that we can actually see your current result.

Comment: Add `document.getElementById("box" + currentBoxNum).style.borderColor = background;` to change the color.

Comment: What is the problem? Or I mean... What is your question? When do you get "Cannot read property 'style' of null" It seems to work fine here.

Comment: I have added a JSfiddle to be more descriptive. I see that it works in the example, but can't seem to get it to work on my program.

Comment: So you want to use Jquery to achieve the same thing? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I want to add a border to whatever box the user clicks on. Then remove the border on the box of the previous one. I'm trying to implement basically a highlighter of what color is currently being displayed. So whatever box has a border, then that is the color being displayed. I cannot use JQuery. Only javascript ,html, and css. This is for a class project.

Comment: In the fiddle you're using `addEventListener` to attach the events, but using a simple reference for the handler. This way only the event object is passed to the handler function. You need similar references as what you have in the code in the question, i.e. `function() { changeColor("#e6e2cf",1); }` etc.

Comment: You have BOTH addeventlisteners and clickevents attached to the html elements (boxes). If you remove the addeventlisters it works.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I'm still new to Javascript. It works now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call the `changeColor` twice. Second thing You can do what you want in less code.

See this working example here.

[You can check the updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/6uhtrczx/1/)

```js
var currentBoxNum = 1;

function changeColor(background, boxNum) {
  document.getElementById("box" + currentBoxNum).style.borderStyle = "none";
  currentBoxNum = boxNum;
  document.getElementById("box" + currentBoxNum).style.borderStyle = "solid";
  document.getElementById("box" + currentBoxNum).style.borderColor = "black";
}

document.getElementById("box1").addEventListener("click", function(){ changeColor("#e6e2cf", 1); });
document.getElementById("box2").addEventListener("click", function(){ changeColor("#dbcaac", 2); });
document.getElementById("box3").addEventListener("click", function(){ changeColor("#c9cbb3", 3); });
document.getElementById("box4").addEventListener("click", function(){ changeColor("#bbc9ca", 4); });
document.getElementById("box5").addEventListener("click", function(){ changeColor("#a6a5b5", 5); });
document.getElementById("box6").addEventListener("click", function(){ changeColor("#b5a6ab", 6); });
document.getElementById("box7").addEventListener("click", function(){ changeColor("#eccfcf", 7); });
document.getElementById("box8").addEventListener("click", function(){ changeColor("#eceeeb", 8); });
document.getElementById("box9").addEventListener("click", function(){ changeColor("#bab9b5", 9); });
```

```css
#box1 {
  background-color: #e6e2cf;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#box2 {
  background-color: #dbcaac;
}

#box3 {
  background-color: #c9cbb3;
}

#box4 {
  background-color: #bbc9ca;
}

#box5 {
  background-color: #a6a5b5;
}

#box6 {
  background-color: #b5a6ab;
}

#box7 {
  background-color: #eccfcf;
}

#box8 {
  background-color: #eceeeb;
}

#box9 {
  background-color: #bab9b5;
}

.pad {
  margin: 10px;
}

.colors {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.colors>div {
    width: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!-- This is a static file -->
<!-- served from your routes in server.js -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Show me!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script|Homemade+Apple|Indie+Flower|Long+Cang&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
  <main>
    <div class="pad">
      <h2 class="choose_pad">Choose your color</h2>
      <div class="colors">
        <div id="box1">1</div>
        <div id="box2">2</div>
        <div id="box3">3</div>
        <div id="box4">4</div>
        <div id="box5">5</div>
        <div id="box6">6</div>
        <div id="box7">7</div>
        <div id="box8">8</div>
        <div id="box9">9</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </main>
  <footer>
    <p class="msg">
      Made on Glitch!
    </p>
    <!-- adds the glitch button at the bottom -->
    <div class="glitchButton"></div>
    <script src="https://button.glitch.me/button.js"></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're calling

```
document.getElementById("cb").style.backgroundColor = background;
```

There is no element with an `id` of `"cb"`.

Update your code to properly reference the `id` of the element you wish to change the background color for.

Comment: You can ignore that. Sorry that is not part of it. That part is working properly. It is just the border portion that is not correctly working. I will take that part out.

Answer (score 0):

Missing line: `document.getElementById("box" + currentBoxNum).style. borderColor = background;`

```js
var currentBoxNum = 1;

function changeColor(background, boxNum) {
  document.getElementById("box" + currentBoxNum).style.borderStyle = "none";
  currentBoxNum = boxNum;
  document.getElementById("box" + currentBoxNum).style.borderStyle = "solid";
  document.getElementById("box" + currentBoxNum).style. borderColor = background;
}
box1.onclick = function() { changeColor("#e6e2cf",1); }
box2.onclick = function() { changeColor("#dbcaac",2); }
box3.onclick = function() { changeColor("#c9cbb3",3); }
box4.onclick = function() { changeColor("#bbc9ca",4); }
box5.onclick = function() { changeColor("#a6a5b5",5); }
box6.onclick = function() { changeColor("#b5a6ab",6); }
box7.onclick = function() { changeColor("#eccfcf",7); }
box8.onclick = function() { changeColor("#eceeeb",8); }
box9.onclick = function() { changeColor("#bab9b5",9); }
```

```html
<div class="colors">
  <div id="box1">1</div>
  <div id="box2">2</div>
  <div id="box3">3</div>
  <div id="box4">4</div>
  <div id="box5">5</div>
  <div id="box6">6</div>
  <div id="box7">7</div>
  <div id="box8">8</div>
  <div id="box9">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added border color, but it still does not seem to work. I have added a JSFiddle link in the original post and here https://jsfiddle.net/5op0d7zs/7/.

Answer (score 0):

You can change you changeColor method as below

```
function changeColor(background, boxNum) {
    $('.colors div').css('border', 'none'); // This will remove borders from all boxes
    document.getElementById("box" + boxNum).style.borderStyle = "solid";
    document.getElementById("box" + boxNum).style.borderColor = background;
```

}

Since this method is using jQuery, please include the jQuery in your html as below,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also, this is just adding the border color not background color. If you want to add the background color as well you can add the following statement in changeColor function

```
document.getElementById("box" + boxNum).style.backgroundColor = background;
```